# HUGE iTextSharp5 perfomance review/refactor

Tags: multithreading, itext

First of all sorry for my poor English.
I made some iTextSharp review and profiling and found a huge amount of perfomance-related problems especially in multi-thread scenario. I made some massive refactoring which **improve perfomance up to 300% (from ~100 seconds to ~25 seconds)**. There was too much unnecessary locks at one side and some stupid threading errors at other side. For example "Image.cs line 1352"

```
    /// <summary>
    /// generates new serial id
    /// </summary>
    static protected long GetSerialId() {
        lock (serialId) {
            serialId = (long)serialId + 1L;
            return (long)serialId;
        }
    }
```

this is NOT a thread safe code since you change lock object. let's say 2 threads (A and B) will wait for lock while another thread (C) is in lock section. So those A nd B threads waits for value "1" but thread C changed them to "2". Once C exit lock race betwen A and B begins (they both can enter a section in some time because "1" is no more locked).
There are much better Interlocked.Increment function

So my changes do

1. review every lock() into code, replace 90% with more effective Interocked and ReaderWriterLockSlim
2. since PdfName used extreme often as dictionary key -> review PdfName.GetHashCode (replace with FNV1a hashe), review PdfName.Equals (replace with fast byte array comparition)
3. review and remove unnececcary lock in PdfObject constructor
4. replace uneffective walk-over-PdfDictionary pattern:

   foreach(var name in dic.Keys){
     var obj = dic.Get(name);// unnececarry hashtable lookup here 
   }
   foreach(var kv in dic){ // PdfDictionary now implements IEnumerable{KeyValue}
     var name = kv.Key;
     var obj = kv.Value;
   }
5. some improvements in IRandomAccessSource. File-based random source are now thread safe and very fast since it used MemoryMapped file instead of file stream
6. ability to provide my own ZLib compression via global static delegate (replacing managed ZLib to unmananaged got perfomance boost)

Unfortunally I have no time to deal with Github to create pull request etc. Is community interested in my work? I can upload zipped sources somewhere so anybody can help me to create pull request and commit those changes into main repository...

Comment: iText(Sharp) 5 is in maintenance mode.. This means that no new development is done on version 5 (it has been successfully used since 2009). If you want to do any efforts on improving iText, don't waste your time with iText 5, focus on iText 7 instead. Your post is not a question that is eligible for Stack Overflow. You *should* do a pull request on the github repository instead. It's not that much work, is it? (But make sure to do this on iText 7, *not iText5!*)

Comment: Are these changes portable to the Java version? Are you aware that iText 5 is in maintenance mode and all new development happens in iText 7? Do you have tests covering all your changes? That being said, that pull request is always welcome, or in whatever other way you want to send it to iText Software.

Comment: I have send you email no reply

Comment: We're working on it.